# mysqli_query only returning results when there's a WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL query is only showing information if I have a condition in the SQL statement.

I've successfully used the SQL statement in phpmyadmin and it works great. I've changed the table name in the PHP code and it functions properly, the "people" table is the only one that causes a problem.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnectLocal.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE nameFirst = 'Karen'";

$billings = array();

$billingResults = mysqli_query($connL, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($billingResults)){
    $billings[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($connL);

$jsonOutput = json_encode($billings);

print("<pre>".json_encode($billings, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>");
?>
```

The above code produces the desired result, it gives me a JSON result of everyone whos name is Karen. But if I were to change it to $sql = "SELECT * FROM people" I get a blank screen.

Comment: Maybe you're running out of memory because the table is so big. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: `where 1 =1` returns successful as well? You should use some error reporting as well.

Comment: how many records in your `people` table are you dealing with?

Comment: How many people is in your table? This may be due to a memory size exhausted. Check in your /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: The table only has 1344 records and 36 columns. It's not huge my any stretch. I am the only user who accesses it. I'm using XAMPP could that be causing a problem?

Comment: Post your table definition, CREATE statement; for all we know, half of those 36 fields are high resolution images of fingerprints.

Comment: I've added `var_dump($billingResults);` just after `$billingResults = mysqli_query($connL, $sql);` and I get `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(36) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1334) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Answer (score 0):

Json have 4 mb limitation. You can make a var_dump of $billings to check what you get from db

Answer (score 0):

After much digging around and frustration, it turned out to be a json_encode error. Specifically a UTF8 problem. Found this solution on php.net. I ran the array through this function before encoding it and it worked perfect.

```
function utf8ize($d) {
if (is_array($d)) {
foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
$d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
}
} else if (is_string ($d)) {
return utf8_encode($d);
}
return $d;
}
```